# Excel VBA - Paste as values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a function that copies the information from one sheet to another but I'm struggling with the *paste as values function*. Do you know why it is not working?

```
Sub Copy_Data()
    Dim Src As Worksheet, Dst As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, r As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    'Change these to the correct sheet names
    Set Src = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Dst = Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = Src.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each r In Src.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        If (Month(r.Value) = "2" And Year(r.Value) = "1902") Then
            If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
            Else
                Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could miss out the clipboard entirely:

```
If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
    Dst.Range("A1").Resize(CopyRange.Rows.Count, CopyRange.Columns.Count).Value = CopyRange.Value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
CopyRange.Copy 
Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

but you can also just do

```
 Dst.EntireRow.Value = CopyRange.EntireRow.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `pastespecial` you need to have the copy and paste statements in separate commands. Note that even if you were doing a "normal" paste, you'd not have `.Paste` after declaring the destination-range. I think it is also a good idea to set `Application.CutCopyMode` to false after the operation, though I am not positive about this.

The correct syntax would be something like:

```
If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
  CopyRange.Copy
  Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteType:=xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311601/2685412) is correct but I'll just elaborate because this question has appeared tons of times here in SO. Eirikdaude is correct about using the correct syntax which is:

> *expression*.**Copy(*Destination*)**

from [MSDN Range Object Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx).
So this line will work:

```
Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Range("B1")
```

*Destination* argument requires a range where you want your data to be transferred.
 Supplying this argument skips the *clip board* while omitting it will copy the range to the clip board (again as stated in the link).

Now, your code: `CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)`
does not meet above requirements. Why?

1. It doesn't meet the syntax where the *Destination* argument should be a range. Instead, you passed a `Method of a Range Object` which is `PasteSpecial`.
2. You didn't omit the argument so the *Range* was not pass to *clip board*.

To make it work, you need to do it like Eirikdaude did which is *separating the statements in two(2) lines.*

```
CopyRange.Copy ' omit the argument so range is passed in clip board
Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' execute PasteSpecial method
```

But he also added this line:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clears the clip board
```

That is used to clear the *clip board*. Remember that when you execute `Copy` without the *Destination* argument, you passed it to the *clip board* so you have to clear it (at least in my opinion).

You can have it in one line though like this:

```
CopyRange.Copy: Dst.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Above will work as well. Take note of the colon **`:`** after `CopyRange.Copy`.
That is a *line (statement) separating character* which indicates that what follows it is treated as a *new line* or in another perspective as a *statement separator* to indicate the end of an individual statement.